# jQuery and/or markItUp! choking on CTRL key

Tags: jquery, markitup

I've inherited the company website and a hastily thrown together CMS along with it. Got my first bug today and I'm stumped.

The CMS uses markItUp!, which I'd never heard of before. The problem is this: whenever someone types the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> character into the affected textarea, jQuery throws a lovely `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [ctrl character]` exception.

I'm looking at the markItUp! keyPressed function and I don't see how it would *ever* work, under the circumstances. To use the shortcuts, you must preface them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, but keyPressed will always fire after you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, not find <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in the set, hence error in `Sizzle.filter`.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with textarea in focus, then:

```
//jquery.markitup.js

    function keyPressed(e) { 
       shiftKey = e.shiftKey;
       altKey = e.altKey;
       ctrlKey = (!(e.altKey && e.ctrlKey)) ? e.ctrlKey : false;

       if (e.type === 'keydown') {
          if (ctrlKey === true) {
             //Line below attempts to find an anchor tag with accesskey CTRL character
             li = $("a[accesskey="+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)+"]", header).parent('li');
             //SNIP
          }
       }
    }


    //jquery-1.5.js

    Sizzle.filter = function( expr, set, inplace, not ) {
       var count = 0;
       var match, anyFound,
          old = expr,
          result = [],
          curLoop = set,
          isXMLFilter = set && set[0] && Sizzle.isXML( set[0] );

       //expr = the CTRL character, set = the markItUp! default set
       while ( expr && set.length) {
          for ( var type in Expr.filter ) {
             if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) != null && match[2] ) {
                //SNIP
             }
          }

          // Improper expression
          if ( expr === old ) {
             if ( anyFound == null ) {
                Sizzle.error( expr );
             } else {
               break;
             }
          }

          old = expr;
       }
       return curLoop;
    };

    Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
       throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg;
    };
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It sounds like your selector expression has a syntax error - try checking the string that this selector is creating: `$("a[accesskey="+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)+"]", header)`

Comment: I agree with that observation.  However, if that is the case, then why does it work for everyone else? I didn't write that line -- it's part of the markItUp codebase.

Comment: Browser difference? Is the bug being reported on a different browser version than you are testing on? Are you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: It was reported in IE8, I am running IE8 and FireFox 6. Same problem in both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

For me it only happens with a new version of jQuery (1.7.1). If I use 1.4.2, it doesn't report any error. No matter which browser I use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed with the jquery 1.5 compatibility patch in this [commit](https://github.com/markitup/1.x/commit/indent).

The relevant line in the patch was:

```
-            li = $("a[accesskey="+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)+"]", header).parent('li');
+            li = $('a[accesskey="'+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)+'"]', header).parent('li');
```